# Azure Databricks - Unable to create symlink

Tags: databricks, symlink, delta-lake

I am trying to create symlink on databricks delta table which is on ADLS(Azure) with the below command.

```
%sql
%sql
GENERATE symlink_format_manifest FOR TABLE schema_name.`dbfs:/filepath`;
```

which fails with the below error:
`Error in SQL statement: NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'dbfs:/filepath' not found in database 'schema_name';`

Answer (score 1):

You should be referring to a delta table either by using

```sql
delta.`abfss://<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/<file_name>`
```

or when your ADLS is mounted to you DBFS:

```sql
delta.`/mnt/<path>/<file_name>`
```

or when using a hive table

```sql
delta.`/mnt/<path>/<file_name>`
```

you can't however link to a file on the filesystem that way

Comment: Thanks Dr.Casual, Yes ADLS is mounted DBFS. When you say file_name am i going to pass all file names? because i have more than one parquet file in ADLS within the table name folder(Eg: mnt/delta_talbe/<table_name>/parque1, parque2....

Comment: You could pass the folder where the files are in, spark is then smart enough to loop over the files :)

Comment: tried that as well looks like it doesn't support Azure storage(it throws error saying it support only AWS S3). I was asked to set the property but not sure how we should do SET spark.databricks.delta.symlinkFormatManifest.fileSystemCheck.enabled = false. I also tried  python mode from delta.tables import *
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(path = 'dbfs:/mnt/path/', sparkSession = spark)
deltaTable.generate('symlink_format_manifest') which thrown warning on deltaTable.generate('symlink_format_manifest').

Comment: Just set it as the error suggests as so `spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.symlinkFormatManifest.fileSystemCheck.enabled", 'false')`.